# Refund Oyster Card online

Tags: refunds, oyster-card

I claimed to refund my Oyster card and got an email that says my Oyster card refund has been processed.
Refund payment method: Web Accounts Credit

BUT I think I never provide my credit information on the website. How do they make payment to my account?

Answer (score 11):

Web Accounts Credit means that you get the money on your web account that you have created for the oyster card refund on tfl.gov.uk. After that your oyster card will not work anymore and instead of money on your oyster card you have your  money  on your newly created web account. You can use this money for other services on the website or even ask for refund to your bank account.

> You may redeem your web account balance at any time. You can get this
>   paid into your bank account by entering your bank account number and
>   sort code online. Only the entire 'cash' balance may be redeemed- you
>   can't redeem part of it. Source: https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/terms-and-conditions/online-accounts